# AppleScript counting and recording entries

Tags: applescript

I’m extremely new to AppleScript; I feel like I’m getting the hang of it, but for the purposes of this question, assume I don’t know a lot.

I’m trying to make a program to log my daily running. So far, I have got it to display how far I ran for one day and how long it took (I also have the average speed) with the following code:

```
display alert "Do you know how far you ran today?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button "Yes"
set ans to button returned of the result
if ans is "No" then
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        do JavaScript "window.open('maps.google.com/')"; in document 1
    end tell
end if
set dis to text returned of (display dialog "How many miles did you run today?" default answer "")
set tim to text returned of (display dialog "How many minutes did that take?" default answer "")
set speed to tim / dis
display dialog "Today you ran " & dis & " miles in " & tim & "minutes" & return & "at a " & speed & " minute mile pace."
end
```

What I’d like is some way to get the average distance, time and speed for the week, as well as the total distance. I would also like it to keep track of the average distance time and speed and total distance ever. Ideally, the script would output something like:

> Today you ran x miles in x minutes at an x minute pace. You've recently averaged x miles in x minutes at an x minute pace. In total, you've ran for x minutes, running x miles at an x minute mile pace

I think one would go about that by adding the last day’s data to the average number multiplied by however many entries and then divide that by the entries plus one, but I don’t know how to do that and there’s probably an easier way.

Comment: Something like this requires some form of persistent storage (a way to keep track of things between one time you run the script and the next), which AppleScript isn't really built for. There are ways to do it, but you would likely have an easier time of this if you went for a scripting language more suited to that sort of thing (i.e. with easier ways to parse text or interact with a database than AppleScript).

Comment: Nathan could be right. There may be simpler solutions however applescript is simple anyway. This task doesn't seem too complex. You can read/write lists and records to a file. You can issue sqlite3 commands if you prefer a database solution. You can even use plist files or applescript's database events. I just need the poster to give some direction about how he wants it to work before I can help. I'd like to see some code too.

Comment: 'display alert "Do you know how far you ran today?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button "Yes"
set ans to button returned of the result
if ans is "No" then
 tell application "Safari"
  activate
  do JavaScript "window.open('https://maps.google.com/')" in document 1
 end tell
 
end if
set dis to text returned of (display dialog "How many miles did you run today?" default answer "")
set tim to text returned of (display dialog "How many minutes did that take?" default answer "")
set speed to tim / dis

Comment: display dialog "Today you ran " & dis & " miles in " & tim & "minutes" & return & "at a " & speed & " minute mile pace."


end'

Comment: so @regulus6633, i guess to be more specific, it asks if I know how far i ran, and if i don't, it pulls up google maps, then it asks for distance and time, calculates speed, and then displays it. and upon thinking about it, what i would like it to do is also display the average distance time and speed for the past 5 entries (because I feel like that would be easier, and probably more useful than per week) , and also display the total distance and time (and average speed from that) ever recorded. so in the end I'd like it to say this. do you think that's do able?

Comment: "Today you ran x miles in x minutes at an x minute pace. You've recently averaged x miles in x minutes at an x minute pace. In total, you've ran for x minutes, running x miles at an x minute mile pace"

Comment: @user1533509: you can delete these last three comments: I inserted the code in your question. In the future, please do edit your question to add information requested in the comments – this makes it much easier for people reading your question than forcing them to browse through the comment thread, part of which SO hides by default.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed like an interesting problem so I wrote you a script. Your running records are saved to a file in your application support folder called RunningTracker.txt. Each record is a list consisting of {the date, the miles, the minutes}.

If you ever need to modify the file of running records you can just read the file into applescript, adjust the list-of-lists as necessary, and write it back to the file. The reading and writing part of that can be copied from the code below.

Anyway, here's the code. Good luck.

```
property appName : "RunningTracker"
set saveFile to (path to application support folder from user domain as text) & appName & ".txt"

-- initial question
display dialog "Do you know how far you ran today?" buttons {"Show Statistics", "No", "Yes"} default button "Yes" with title appName
set ans to button returned of the result
if ans is "No" then
    open location "http://maps.google.com"
    return
else if ans is "Show Statistics" then
    set showStatistics to true
else
    set showStatistics to false
end if

-- get the list of stored records
set theRecords to {}
try
    set theRecords to read file saveFile as list -- get the stored values
end try

-- get todays record and save it to the saveFile
if showStatistics then
    if theRecords is {} then
        display dialog "There are no running records yet. Please create a record before proceeding!" buttons {"Quit"} default button 1 with title appName
        return
    else
        set todaysRecord to item -1 of theRecords
    end if
else
    set todaysRecord to getNewRecord()
    set end of theRecords to todaysRecord
    set success to writeTo(saveFile, theRecords, list, false)
    if not success then
        display dialog "Error: could not write todays data to the saveFile!" buttons {"Quit"} default button 1 with title appName
        return
    end if
end if

-- create todays statistics
set todayDate to item 1 of todaysRecord
set todayMiles to item 2 of todaysRecord
set todayMins to item 3 of todaysRecord
set todaysStatistic to dateString(todayDate) & return & todayMiles & " miles in " & todayMins & " mins ==> " & decimalRound(todayMins / todayMiles, 2) & " mins/mile"

-- create weekly and total statistics
set weeklyMiles to 0
set weeklyMins to 0
set totalMiles to 0
set totalMins to 0
set secondsPerWeek to 7 * days
set weeklyDate to missing value
repeat with aRecord in my theRecords
    set thisDate to item 1 of aRecord
    if (todayDate - thisDate) is less than or equal to secondsPerWeek then
        if weeklyDate is missing value then set weeklyDate to (item 1 of aRecord)
        set weeklyMiles to weeklyMiles + (item 2 of aRecord)
        set weeklyMins to weeklyMins + (item 3 of aRecord)
    end if
    set totalMiles to totalMiles + (item 2 of aRecord)
    set totalMins to totalMins + (item 3 of aRecord)
end repeat
set weeklyStatistic to dateString(weeklyDate) & " - " & dateString(todayDate) & return & weeklyMiles & " miles in " & weeklyMins & " mins ==> " & decimalRound(weeklyMins / weeklyMiles, 2) & " mins/mile"
set totalStatistic to "Total (" & (count of theRecords) & " records)" & return & totalMiles & " miles in " & totalMins & " mins ==> " & decimalRound(totalMins / totalMiles, 2) & " mins/mile"

-- display the statistics
display dialog todaysStatistic & return & return & weeklyStatistic & return & return & totalStatistic buttons {"Quit"} default button 1 with title appName


(*========== SUBROUTINES ============*)
on getNewRecord()
    set dis to text returned of (display dialog "How many miles did you run today?" default answer "" with title appName)
    set tim to text returned of (display dialog "How many minutes did that take?" default answer "" with title appName)
    return {current date, dis as number, tim as number}
end getNewRecord

on writeTo(targetFile, theData, dataType, apendData) -- write to a file
    try
        set targetFile to targetFile as text
        set openFile to open for access file targetFile with write permission
        if apendData is false then set eof of openFile to 0
        write theData to openFile starting at eof as dataType
        close access openFile
        return true
    on error
        try
            close access file targetFile
        end try
        return false
    end try
end writeTo

on decimalRound(theNum, sigDigits) -- round a number
    try
        theNum as number
        sigDigits as number
        set roundedNum to (round (10 ^ sigDigits * theNum) rounding as taught in school) / (10 ^ sigDigits)
    on error
        set roundedNum to theNum
    end try
    return roundedNum
end decimalRound

on dateString(d)
    return ((month of d) as text) & space & day of d & ", " & year of d
end dateString
```

Comment: oh my gosh thanks so much ! how long did it take to learn all this stuff? im really interested in the practical aspect, like writing stuff like that that makes stuff like this a lot easier.

Comment: You're welcome. I wrote it in less than an hour. I think you could learn enough to create this script in a month or so... depending on how much you practice. Of course it will take you much longer to create the code but the required skills for this task aren't too great. The math is simple and you already have that skill. The complex part is thinking up the strategy. All this script does is work with a list-of-lists and then read/write it to disk.

Comment: Here's a tip. Code that you expect to use over-and-over, make that into generic subroutines. Then when you create new scripts you just re-use those subroutines. For example you can see I have subroutines for writing to disk and for rounding numbers. I just plugged that code into this script which makes writing this script much easier as I don't have to think about those things again. So keep those subroutines and use them in other code your write.